# Server slows same time every day, no idea why

Tags: linux, centos, mediatemple

I have a DV server from MediaTemple and lately our server is slowing at the same time every day. It is not due to a traffic increase or anything like that. The slow down lasts 2-3 hours.

It seems like everything takes longer to respond and download from the server. A simple 50kb image takes 1-2 seconds instead of being instant.

MediaTemple can not tell what is causing the slow down. Server resources are good, cpu usage is very low, plenty of disk space.

Any ideas what can cause something like this like clock work every day? Something hidden that wouldn't be detected by MediaTemple?

Comment: Can you run a benchmark on storage IO during the slowdown and at normal times?

Comment: Take a look at what you have in your crontab and cron.daily

Comment: You should also monitor the connection to the server with a tool such as `mtr` and look if there is a slow down or packet loss when things go bad.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those things. It's just so frustrating. According to server statistics we are using like no resources. It seems the response time is just totally delayed.

Comment: Yes, benchmark on storage IO, e.g. with iostat.   Hunch: Nightly backups?

Comment: That's what we thought at first but MediaTemple says no. Could this be a spam bot trying to user our email or would that be reflected in server stats (cpu, memory, etc.)?

Comment: I would imagine MediaTemple would pick something like that up but you could check `/var/log/maillog` in case. Did you check crontab and cron.daily as @gview suggested?